# How to change hyperlink behavior from double-click to single-click

Tags: php, html

here is my code, i would like my links to open with just a single click. all is functioning properly, its just that, the delete,approve ant not approve link must be double click for its function to run. i hope someone could hear me.

***index.php***

```
<?php       
                            $search = '%';
                            $fgmembersite->DBLogin();
                            $limit = 5;
                            if(isset($_GET['offset'])) {
                                $offset = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['offset']);
                            } else {
                                $offset = 0;
                            }

                            //for namelist a-z
                            $listname = '%';
                            If (isset($_GET['namelist']))
                            {                                   
                                $listname = $_GET['namelist'];
                            }

                            //for search file
                            if(isset($_POST['searchfile']))
                            {
                                $search = $_POST['searchfile'];
                            }                               
                            else if(isset($_GET['searchfile']))
                            {
                                $search = $_GET['searchfile'];
                            }

                            if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa' OR $_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'admin')
                            {                                   
                                    $sql="select * from gmdc_employee where employee_name like '%$search%' AND employee_name like '$listname%' ";                                                                                           
                            }
                            else
                            {                                   
                                $sql = "select b.* from gmdc_user a, gmdc_employee b where a.username = '".$_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()]."' and a.company_id = b.company_id AND b.employee_name like '$listname%' AND b.employee_name like '%$search%'"; 

                            }
                            $query = mysql_query("$sql ORDER BY employee_name,confirmation DESC ,file_id DESC,file_date DESC LIMIT $offset,$limit") or die ( mysql_error () );
                            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
                            $total = mysql_num_rows($result);

                            if(!$result || mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0)
                            {
                                $fgmembersite->HandleError("No file found.");
                                return false;
                            }
                            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
                            {
                                $file_id = $row['file_id'];
                                $file_desc = $row['file_description'];
                                $file_date = $row['file_date'];
                                $file_name = $row['file_name'];
                                $file_accs = $row['folder_access'];
                                $file_employee  = $row['employee_id'];
                                $file_confir = $row['confirmation'];
                                $file_ename = ucwords($row['employee_name']);


                                $info = pathinfo($file_name);
                                $file_ext = $info['extension'];                                 



                                echo '<tr>
                                    <td>
                                        &nbsp; 
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="subone">
                                    <td class="sub" width="100">
                                        '.$file_employee.'
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>';
                                    if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
                                    {

                                    ?><td class="sub" width="100">
                                        <a href="" onclick = javascript:newPopup('addfile.php?emp=<?php echo $file_employee ?>');><?php echo$file_ename?></a>
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td><?php
                                    }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            echo '<td class="sub" width="182">
                                            '.$file_ename.' 
                                            <br />
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </td>';
                                        }


                                    echo'<td  class="sub" width="218">
                                        <a href="'.$file_accs.$file_name.'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline;">'.$file_desc.'</a>
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td  class="sub" width="100">
                                        '.date('M d, Y',mktime(0,0,0,substr($file_date,5,2),substr($file_date,8,2),substr($file_date,0,4))).'
                                        <br />
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                    <td  class="sub" width="100">   
                                                '.$file_confir.'                
                                    <br />
                                            &nbsp;
                                            </td>';
                                    if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'sa')
                                    {
                                        if($file_confir == 'Pending' OR $file_confir == 'NotApproved')
                                        {                                               
                                            if(isset($_GET['id']))
                                            {
                                                $fgmembersite->Delete_Db($_GET['id']);
                                            }
                                                echo '<td  class="sub" width="100"> 
                                                <a href="index.php?id='.$file_id.'">Delete</a>
                                                <br />
                                                &nbsp;
                                                </td>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if($_SESSION[$fgmembersite->GetLoginSessionVar()] == 'admin')
                                        {
                                            if($file_confir == 'Pending')
                                            {   

                                                    if(isset($_GET['yes']))
                                                    {
                                                        $fgmembersite->UpdateYesDB($_GET['yes']);
                                                    }
                                                    else if(isset($_GET['no']))
                                                    {
                                                        $fgmembersite->UpdateNoDB($_GET['no']);
                                                    }
                                                    echo'<td  class="sub" width="100">  
                                                    <a href="index.php?yes='.$file_id.'">Approve</a>                                            
                                                    <br /><br />
                                                    <a href="index.php?no='.$file_id.'">NotApprove</a>                                      
                                                    &nbsp;
                                                    </td> ';
                                            }   
                                        }
                                    }?>
```

***fg_membersite.php***

```
function Delete_Db($id)
{   
    $ok = mysql_query("DELETE FROM gmdc_employee WHERE file_id='$id'");

    if (!$ok) 
    {
        $this->HandleError("Error deleting profile from database!");
    }


}
function UpdateYesDB($fid)
{
        $this->DBLogin();
        $yes = mysql_query("UPDATE gmdc_employee SET confirmation='Approved' WHERE file_id = '$fid'");          
        if (!$yes) 
        {
            $this->HandleError("Error updating from database!");
            return false;
        }
}
function UpdateNoDB($fids)
{
        $this->DBLogin();
        $no = mysql_query("UPDATE gmdc_employee SET confirmation='NotApproved' WHERE file_id = '$fids'");           
        if (!$no) 
        {
            $this->HandleError("Error updating from database!");
            return false;
        }   
}
```

*note, i only put the delete/approve/not approve function because thats my only problem. thanks

Comment: Can you show us the link's HTML?

Comment: What does your html look like? And do you use and JavaScript that might affect the html for update and/or delete?

Comment: I did not use javascript on my delete/update

Comment: You are using plain html links, so a single click should do. If that's not the case then _something_ changes the behavior of the links, and that something is most likely JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir Arjan, the problem is, the delete/approve/not approve links must be double click and i would like it to only work insingle clicks.

Comment: @MisaChan - it's important that you leave your question in place. If other people find they have the same problem, they will google and might find your code... and then they will find the answers that came with it and will be able to solve their own problem. if you delete your original question - they will not find help. So I have rolled back your question to the previous version. Feel free to edit it to make it clearer what the problem was - but please don't just delete it all and leave a message saying you fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify the quote usage in the section as follows.

```
echo "<td  class='sub' width='100'><a href='index.php?yes=".$file_id."'>Approve</a><br /><br /><a href='index.php?no=".$file_id."'>NotApprove</a></td>";
```

Please let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: the code produces a parse error when i tried it, i figured out that my codes are really correct and it updates the file on the first click. its just that it wont reload. is there anyway that i could reload the page without causing problem to the update/delete?

Comment: Could you please provide the css for class sub ? It will be better if you could share the source view of that section from the browser.

Comment: actually the css is for the disign of the program, like margin, size, position

Comment: Which browser are you using to test the site? Could you please try the same page in a different browser or different machine?

Comment: this php file is not yet uploaded and i am using a mozilla firefox, i haven't finished this php file as well and is still on going

Comment: I just corrected the syntax error in the code. Sorry for the mistake.. Could you please take the source code and let me know how this section appears. eg.<div id="code-output" class="code-output"><a href="index.php?yes=5">Approve</a><br><br><a href="index.php?no=5">NotApprove</a></div>

Answer (score 5):

HTML links do typically not require double clicks, you probably have some other element that is overlapping your link or some script that is interfering.

Please show the complete source for the affected page.

Try looking at your completed markup in a tool like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Comment: this one is already solved by myself,but thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you could provide me the code of that link. I am wondering whether you are using Javascript function or just link to go to a new page from update and delete Anchor tag.

Comment: You just miss a quotes there in the <a href> and it is the issue

Comment: i tried doing that but it causes an error, i figured out that my codes are really correct and it updates the file on the first click. its just that it wont reload. is there anyway that i could reload the page without causing problem to the update/delete?

Comment: Okay, let me check. Is there any way for you to share the link to that page? Are you sure it works when you double click?

Comment: yes, i have tried it many times. but i cant share the link to that page since its not yet uploaded. but here is the concept of the page:

Comment: when an IT upload a file to the page, the file could be seen by the admin(who checks the uploaded file and decides whether the uploaded file is accepted or not). here's the thing, the admin is given two new table column for the approve and not approve, when the admin clicks on the approve link, the database is updated and same goes with the NotApprove link. the only difference between the two is the content (Approve, the other NotApprove). all codes works properly except for one thing,when you click on the link, it wont reload,although it is updated on the first click